# Moodle SQL-Statement to show all Messages that habe been sent to a user with special id

Tags: sql, moodle

How can I use SQL to query which messages were sent to the user with ID 100?

Comment: Not seeing any question asked here?

Comment: @Stu i see one tho? ^^(just joking). Concerning what's asked, you want to use sql within your sql engin (then which one is it? What have you tried?). Or do you want to do it within php code in a plugin, (then can you show us what you've tried?)

Comment: @Veterini review the edit history.

Comment: The question has been revised and has been answered by other users.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 message tables in Moodle, before and after a message is read

`||` is the concat operator in Postgresql

```
SELECT 'message' || id AS uniqueid,
    useridfrom,
    useridto,
    subject,
    fullmessage,
    contexturl,
    contexturlname,
    timecreated,
    0 AS timeread,
    timeuserfromdeleted,
    timeusertodeleted
FROM mdl_message
WHERE useridfrom = xx
UNION
SELECT 'messageread' || id AS uniqueid,
    useridfrom,
    useridto,
    subject,
    fullmessage,
    contexturl,
    contexturlname,
    timecreated,
    timeread,
    timeuserfromdeleted,
    timeusertodeleted
FROM mdl_message_read
WHERE useridfrom = xx
```

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions depending on what you're wanting to do:
First in SQL, considering your tables have the MDL_ prefix you can do

```
SELECT * FROM mdl_message WHERE useridfrom = 100;
#there is also the useritto possible
```

If you want to retrieve the user informations you can enhance like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mdl_user WHERE id IN (SELECT * FROM mdl_message WHERE useridfrom = 100)
```

In your plugin code you can do it like following the Moodle DATA API:
https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API

```
<?php
    global $DB;
    /*remember to not apply the table's prefix*/
    $messages = $DB->get_records('message', array('useridfrom'=>100));
```

Comment: #there is also the useritto possible

In my mdl_messages is not a column with useridto. I want to see all messages  that reached the user with ID 100. 

I don't want to see the messages written by the user with ID 100.

The table mdl_message is completely empty.

Comment: this a core table so i'm kinda baffled you don't have the field? Which version of moodle do you use? Concerning the emptiness of the table, if you're sure it should contain some stuff, did you check you don't have a task (cron), running that empties the table?